# How to create MVC5 ActionLink to root route -- without querystring

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating a MVC project, I have a shared partial view, where I want a link to the root site, with a parameter.  So https://site.invalid/j123456-123.  The only way I have been able to do this is using HTML.Raw.  I would prefer to use a method that is more within the MVC conventions.

```
<a href="@Html.Raw(string.Format("/{0}", item.value))">@item.value</a> 
@Html.ActionLink(item.value,null, new{controller="MyController", action=string.Empty, parameter= item.value})
```

The raw html approach works, the actionlink produces `/?parameter=J123456-123`.  I don't want either the ? or the parameter name shown on the links.

I originally tried using the traditional routing, but am now using attribute based routing.

The attribute for the route I want to use is
  `[Route("~/{parameter:regex([aAjJfF]\\d+-\\d+)}", Name = "ViewByParam")]`

My route does get invoked when I make the above request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of ActionLink use RouteLink.  Use the RouteLink that uses the route name, and then include the routename in the routeValues object.

```
@Html.RouteLink(linkText, "ViewByParam", new {controller= "controllerName", action="ViewByParam", id=item.Id})
```

Inside the controller, use the attribute:

```
[Route("~/{id:regex([aAjJfF]\\d+-\\d+)}", Name = "ViewByParam")]
public ActionResult ViewByParam(string id)
```

At least that is what worked for me and what I am currently using...

Answer (score 0):

Html.ActionLink generates a link to a controller action.  So, if you are trying to link to an action called "MyAction" on a controller called "MyController" with a parameter called "parameter" your link would look like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.value, "MyAction", "MyController", new { parameter = item.value }, null)
```

And your controller would look like this (assuming your regex is correct):

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [Route("~/{parameter:regex([aAjJfF]\\d+-\\d+)}", Name = "ViewByParam")]
    public ActionResult MyAction(string parameter)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If the parameter is the name of the action itself on "MyController" then you need to pass it as such

Your link would look like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.value, item.value, "MyController")
```

And your controller would look like this (if item.value = "Parameter")

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [Route("~/Parameter")]
    public ActionResult Parameter()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you are trying to link to something that isn't an action on one of your controllers then you should just use standard html and Razor to form the link

```
<a href="/@(item.value)">@item.value</a>
```